# Landsat 8 Collection 2 (C2) Level 2 Science Product (L2SP)

Tags: remote-sensing, landsat, imagery, landsat-8, digital-image-processing

I am exploring data sources for land surface temperatures (LST) for summer 2021. From Landsat 8 Collection 2 Surface Temperature (https://www.usgs.gov/core-science-systems/nli/landsat/landsat-collection-2?qt-science_support_page_related_con=1#qt-science_support_page_related_con), I can get a surface temperature in kelvin, to which a scale factor has to be applied, and then convert it to Celsius. But I would like to know if this is all the processing this type of data needs before it can be used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to apply a cloud mask (using the QA_PIXEL bits like [this post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/407458/google-earth-engine-understanding-landsat-7-collection-2-qa-pixel-bitwiseand)) to ensure you're only getting surface temps, but otherwise the data are ready to go (once appropriately scaled).